# custom function for mysqli queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying my hand at custom functions in PHP in order to streamline a lot of stuff I'm otherwise doing manually. I'm damn new to custom functions so I'm not sure the limitations. Right now I'm trying to get data with MySQLi using custom functions Here's the code, and then I'll explain the issue:

```
function connect_db($db = 'db_username') {
    iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
    mb_language('uni');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    @ $mysqli = new mysqli('host',$db,'password',$db);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        die('connection error');
    }

}
```

This one seems to be working fine. It's the next function I'm having more trouble with.

**edit:** Updated thanks to Jeremy1026's response

```
function do_query($db = 'default_db', $query) {
    connect_db();
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if(!$result){
        trigger_error("data selection error");
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

My host forces database names and usernames as the same, so if the db name is 'bob' the username to access it will be 'bob' as well, so that's why `$db` shows up twice in the connection.

The problem I'm having is that these two functions are in `functions.php` and being called from another page. I want to be able to pull the results from the query in that other page based on the column name. But I also need to be able to do this with formatting, so then maybe the `while()` loop has to happen on that page and not in a function? I want this to be as universal as possible, regardless of the page or the data, so that I can use these two functions for all connections and all queries of the three databases I'm running for the site.

God I hope I'm being clear.

Big thanks in advance for any suggestions. I've googled this a bit but it's tough to find anything that's not using obsolescent `mysql_` prefixes or anything that's actually returning the data in a way that I can use.

**Update:** I'm now getting the following error when accessing the page in question:

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function query() on a non-object in **/functions.php**`

with the line in question being `$result = $mysqli->query($query);`. I assume that's because it thinks `$query` is undefined, but shouldn't it be getting the definition from being called in the page? This is that page's code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$myArray = do_query($db, $query);
echo $myArray['column_name'];
```

Answer (score 3):

In your 2nd function you aren't returning any data, so it is getting lost. You need to tell it what to return, see below:

```
function do_query($db = 'default_db', $query) {
    connect_db();
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if(!$result){
        trigger_error("data selection error");
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

Then, when using the function you'll do something like:

```
$myArray = do_query($db, 'select column from table');
```

`$myArray` would then be populated with the results of your query.

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in functions.php on line 31`. Is this possibly a conflict w/ my PHP version? I did some searching on this error and found that it may not be good for after 5.1. Or am I missing something else.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `return $result_array;`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: updated the question with your code (thanks!) and the new error I'm getting.

Comment: Try executing your query outside of the function. That way you can confirm if its the function or your mysqli that is having the issue.

Comment: It's working fine until I rely on the function. If I do the connection outside the function it's fine. So what could be wrong with my function that's keeping it from going through?

Answer (score 1):

This is a half-answer. The following single function works in place of the two.

```
function query_db($database, $new_query) {
    $sqli = new mysqli('host', $database, 'password', $database);
    $sqli->set_charset("utf8");

    global $result;
    if($result = $sqli->query($new_query)){
        return $result;
    }
}
```

By adding `global $result` I was able to access the results from the query, run from another page as

```
query_db("username","SELECT * FROM `column`");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
}
```

It's more streamlined than I have without functions, but it's still not idea. If I have the connection to the database in another function, it doesn't work. If I try to put the `while` loop in the combined function, it doesn't work. Better than nothing, I guess.